# ¿Por qué no llega mi petición get?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, rest

Estoy haciendo pruebas con un servidor Rest que estoy haciendo. El siguiente método:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/getUsers")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserProviderImpl userProvider;

    @GetMapping("/checkUser")
    public Boolean userCheck(@RequestBody UserDto user) {
        Boolean userCheck = false;
        try {
            userCheck = userProvider.userCheck(user);
            return userCheck;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return userCheck;
        }
    }
}
```

Al acceder desde el postMan me devuelve correctamente el true y funciona correctamente, pero al intentar llamarlo desde AJAX con la siguiente petición:

```
function checkUser(){
    var usernameVar = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var passwordVar = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var jsonObj = {
            "userName" : usernameVar,
            "password" : passwordVar 
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/getUsers/checkUser",
        data: jsonObj,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == true) {
            }
        }
    });
}
```

La consola del servidor me devuelve este error:

```
  org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: 
  java.io.IOException: Se ha anulado una conexión 
  establecida por el software en su equipo host.
```

¿Sabeis a que se puede deber?

Comment: Qué versión de JQuery estás usando?

Comment: 3.2.1 Es la version

Answer (score 0):

Hola antes que nada estas usando un método GET, usa path params... es decir que en tu uri.
**http://localhost:8080/getUsers/checkUser**

Es mejor que quede como: 
**http://localhost:8080/getUsers/checkUser? username="user"&pwd="123"**

Lo anterior se logra modificando...

```
 @GetMapping("/checkUser")
    public Boolean userCheck(@RequestParam String username,@RequestParam String pwd) {
        Boolean userCheck = false;
        UserDto user=new UserDto();
        user.getUserName(username);
        user.getPassword(pwd);
        try {
            userCheck = userProvider.userCheck(user);
            return userCheck;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return userCheck;
        }
    }
```

Y luego modificas en el ajax...

```
function checkUser(){
    var usernameVar = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var passwordVar = document.getElementById("password").value;


    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/getUsers/checkUser?username="+usernameVar+"&pwd="+passwordVar,
//        data: jsonObj,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == true) {
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Saludos..

Comment: Spring soporta perfectamente el uso de `@RequestBody` con `@GetMapping`

Comment: Muy buenas omar! Gracias por tu aportación pero pero necesito el saber como pasar objetos Json porque lo necesito para seguir avanzando y seguir consumiendo servicios rest

Comment: @Luis Gargallo en ese caso cambia .  @GetMapping("/checkUser") por  @PostMapping("/checkUser")      var data0 = {userName: "user", password : "531"};

var json = JSON2.stringify(data0 ); 

$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "http://localhost:8080/getUsers/checkUser",
 data: json,
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(data) {
 alert('In Ajax');
 }
});    Pruebale

Comment: He estado leyendo y puede que se deba a tener dos IDE, o dos aplicaciones ejecutandose a la vez lo cual no entiendo por que da conflicto. Si lteneis alguna solución os lo agradeceria